# How to close an particular Excel file using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I need to close an particular Excel file (e.g. abcd.xls)  using a Powershell script.

I have tried below scripts, but it's not working.

1st script:

```
get-process *excel* | stop-process -force
```

2nd script:

```
$excel = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$excel.Workbooks | %{if($_.Name -imatch "abcd.xls"){$_.Close()}}
```

Comment: Both your scripts worked as expected for me. What's not working, any errors?

Comment: using 1st script: all the open excel are closing, but i need to cloas a particular excel file only (abcd.xls)
using 2nd script: it's not closing the specified file.

Comment: Any errors when you run the 2nd script?

Comment: 2nd script works for me too, although I'd write it like `$excel.Workbooks | Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'abcd.xls'} | ForEach-Object { $_.Close() }`